# Expectation of Sufficient Statistic

Tags: self-study, expected-value, expectation-maximization, exponential-family

Consider $X \sim B(n,p)$ with pmf $P(X=x) = {{n}\choose{x}} p^x (1-p)^{n-x}$.

The general exponential form of an exponential family distribution is $p(x|\theta) = f(x) g(\theta) e^{\phi(\theta)^T T(x)}$. Writing the binomial distribution in this form, I get $f(x) = {n \choose x}, g(p)=(1-p)^n, \phi(\theta)=\log{\frac{p}{1-p}}, T(x) = x$.

In other words, $x$, the number of successes is a sufficient statistic for the probability of success on each Bernoulli trial, as is to be expected.

I am asked to find:

(1) the expected value of the sufficient statistic, $<T(x)>_{p(x|\theta)}$ (often called the "mean" or "moment" parameter of the distribution).

(2) the maximum likelihood value of the mean parameter in the above question

I have to be honest, I don't really understand the difference between the two questions. So far I have attempted this:

(1) $\theta=p$ so the likelihood $P(x|p)$ is the probability of getting p successes in n trials given a Bernoulli prob of p. i.e. $P(x|p) = {n \choose x} p^x(1-p)^x$.

Then $<T(x)> = \sum_x T(x)P(x|p) = \sum_x x {n \choose x} p^x(1-p)^x$.

At this point, I'm not sure what to do.

(2) I know that for MLE I should find the maximum of $log{L(p)}= log{P(x|p)} = \log{n \choose x} n+ n \log{1-p} + x \log{\frac{p}{1-p}}$. If I differentiate and set to zero, I get that $x = T(x) = np$ which seems right as this is the expected value for $X$ following a binomial distribution.

Am I at all on the right lines here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint #0:** computing the expectation of a sufficient statistic (of which there is an infinity if there is one) is not equivalent or even related to finding the maximum likelihood of $\theta$ (which for one thing depends on the choice of parameterisation $\theta$)

**Hint #1:** check [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_distribution) for the expectation of a Binomial $\mathcal B(n,p)$ random variable

**Hint #2:** solve the likelihood equation in $p$, not in $x$

Comment: Thanks for the reply. To follow up on my original questions:

(1) So I see from your Hint 0, I appear to have done this wrong as I suspected I had done. However, I am still not clear what I am supposed to be doing here? In my case, T(x)=x. How should I compute its expectation if not by the way above?

(2) For the second question, I think my calculation is correct and I see that from the wording of the original question, I was supposed to be solving for the parameter and so I should have rearranged to p=n/x as you suggest.

Comment: (1) compute the expectation of $X$ by identifying the distribution of $X$ (2) yes indeed

Comment: So basically $E(X) = \sum_x x P(X=x) = \sum_x x {n \choose x} p^x (1-p)^{n-x} =... =np$?

Comment: This is presumably only the case because T(X) = X for this particular example? As you said, there are infinitely many possibilities for T(X) and so how could two statisticians be sure they get the same result?

Comment: I do not understand your question: two different functions $T$ have different expectations in most cases, but this is of no consequence as _a statistic is not an estimator_ by default.

Comment: Understand the no consequence but it seems like the question's answer would have a degree of ambiguity in that case. For me, with T(X) = X, I can do $E(T(X)) = \sum_x x P(X=x) =\sum_x x {n \choose x} p^x (1-p)^{n-x} =.... =np$. Meanwhile, my friend could find T(X)=2X and conclude E(T(X)) =2np. So just so I get this right, are you saying both are valid? Thanks.

Comment: Both are sufficient statistics. Both can be used to estimate any function/transform of the parameter, from $p$ to $2p$, to $p^p$...

Comment: Thank you! And just a final check of some terminology: in Q1, it says that the expectation of T(X) is called the mean parameter. According to this answer, the mean parameter of the distribution should be \mu=np (as we expect). In Q2, we are then asked to find the MLE of the mean parameter. Doesn't this suggest I should be using MLE to solve for p and then get an expression for \mu rather than p?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/89779/discussion-between-xian-and-user11128).